# I would like to turn text file into a csv file with multiple rows for various data types

Tags: csv

I don't know how to put this in more professional terms, because I don't know anything about such things, but what I am trying to do is the following: I have a text file of tweets that look like this:

"username: the tweet content - Wed, 14 Dec 2011 13:31:13 +0000 - tweet id 364629346"

Exactly like the above, with quotation marks and all. I would like to have a csv file that has the following columns: tweet_id, created_at, from_user, and text. The created_at would have the date and time (preferably in the following format: month/day/year hour:minute pm) and from user is just the username. And then the text.

I tried to rename the .txt into .csv and use seperated by " - " but that didn't work, obviously.

Could you help me in any way? Is this easily doable? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What software did it not work in? your description doesn't help with trying to solve the problem. Using `-` as separators is easy.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a silly idea. I am using OpenOffice and I ended up with very weirdly formatted text when I tried that. I am sorry, I don't know anything about these at all, I tried to be descriptive, I just haven't done anything like this before.

Comment: You should be able to import the data in as a CSV with - as a separator using calc

Comment: Okay, so I was just very stupid. I tried to seperate by " - " (there were spaces before and after -) but it turns out, it works out fine if I don't have the spaces.

Comment: Ah, no, it doesn't. Because there are dashes in the content of the tweets as well.

Answer (score 0):

When I have things like that to do I just paste the code into dreamweaver and do regular expression find and replaces to get the data as needed and then saved as.

You could always paste it into excel and then sort and save as .csv that way.